# ".apply()" in Pandas to k-th argument

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to apply my own multi-argument function to a Pandas data-frame (or a series within) using the data frame entries as the k-th argument in my N-argument function.

It only seems to work if I pass the dataframe as the first argument. I want to be able to pass the dataframe through one of the other arguments.

```py
# A simple 3 argument function:
def my_func(a, b, c):
    return (a/b)**c

# Data-Frame:
d1 = {
    'column1': [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, ],
    'column2': [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, ]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d1, index = [1, 2, 3])
```

```py
# I can apply it fine if I pass the columns as the first argument i.e. "a":
df.apply(my_func, b=7, c=9)

# However, I am unable to pass the columns through arguments "b" or "c":
df.apply(my_func, a = 7, c = 9)
```

This returns a TypeError: *("my_func() got multiple values for argument 'a'", 'occurred at index column1')*

**I want to be able to pass the columns of the data frame (or series) through any of the arguments of my own multi-argument function. 
Is there a simple/intuitive (non-hack-like) way of doing this?**

Comment: `apply` defaults 1st parameter to the passing column. In your function, it is `a`. You manually pass `a` again, so it errors out.

Comment: You can't, and honestly why would you wanna do that? The series is the first argument by default, makes no sense to pass it as 2nd or nth arg. You can always, however, create your own function wrapper `my_func_wrapper` and reorder the arguments in that, such that `def my_func_wrapper(a,b,c): return my_func(b,a,c)` or smith similar

Comment: @AndyL. : I understand why the error is occuring. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @rafaelc: I have my reasons for wanting to do that. I am not going to use exactly that function or exactly that data frame. I have other use cases when I may want to "recycle" the same function for applying it to different data-frames, etc. Is there any way to pass the data-frame through the other arguments instead without resorting to a function wrapper? 

Thank-you for your help.

Comment: @JWP then wrap it with lambda.. `df.apply(lambda s: myfunc(a, s, c..)`

Comment: I tried this:

```python

df.apply(lambda s: my_func(a = 5, s, c = 7))
```

I then got the error: _SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument._

Comment: `df.apply(lambda s: my_func(5, s['column-or-index'], c = 7))`

Comment: What if I wanted to pass the entire data-frame as "s"?

Comment: than you don't need `.apply`. Probably you'll need to rewrite the function or add a wrapper to make it work with scalars. It's hard to be more precise without a practical example

Comment: if you want to apply the same operation to all cells, then it should be `applymap`. But in this case, I'm not sure where to apply "column-wise"

Comment: @Marat: So it works for specified rows and columns. I am still wondering how to implement this on the whole dataframe. 

Could you please explain it using the specified my_func and the dataframe df as sketched at the start? Thank-you.

Comment: @JWP can you show what result you expect?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly all you need is:

```
my_func(df['column1'], b=7, c=5)
```

Pandas series can be multiplied/divided/taken to power of a constant, returning a series of the same size.

In a more sophisticated scenario, when scalar operations aren't enough, it could also be written as something like:

```
df.apply(lambda row: my_func(row['column1'], b=7, c=5), axis=1)
```

Here `axis=1` tells Pandas to apply this function to row instead of column(default)

To apply this function elementwise, you can use `df.appymap` instead:

```
df.applymap(lambda value: my_func(7, value, c=5)
```

However, it will be **much** faster if `my_func` or its input could be adjusted to use vectors instead:

```
my_func(np.ones(df.shape) * 7, df, c=5)
```

Comment: I can do it fine when I am passing the data frame through "a". I am unable to pass it through "b" having fixed "a" and "c".

Also is there a way to do it column by column? Row-wise applications are slower I think, especially if I only need to apply the function to one or a few of the columns.

Comment: And can the second option be applied column-wise?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by column-wise, but yes. `axis=0` (default) would mean that instead of a row lambda will get a column